# ActionBar title drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm working on a Tablet-optimized app which uses fragments. The target SDK is 14, so I'm not using appcompat or ActionBarSherlock for the `ActionBar`, just the stock API.

When the app is opened on a tablet, I load a master-detail layout. When the app is opened on a handheld device, I load a layout with just 1 pane, and if the user presses a row I replace the Fragment with the detail layout. This is all done in the same Activity.

This works like a charm, except for one detail: If the device is a handheld, I call `getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` on the second Fragment. Also, in the `onResume()` method of the first Fragment I call `getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`. So, if the Main activity receives a `android.R.id.home`as a menu item id, it replaces the first layout with the Master layout, and the arrow dissapears. However, if you click in the app name, it still "glows".

Is there any way of disabling that "glow"? Am I doing something wrong? You can reproduce it by calling `setDisplayHomeAsUp(true)` then later on calling `setDisplayHomeAsUp(false)` in an Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way of disabling that "glow"?

What you're wanting to do is disable the "home" button. Call `ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled` respectively.